# How to modify Tag names in return XML in ASP.net Web service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services, iis

Following web service execute Stored Procedure and return XML without any error.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Xml;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Script.Services;

[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]


// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

public class GetData : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    public GetData()
    {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public XmlElement GetUserDetailsXML(string userName)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ToString());
        con.Open();
        // SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tblUserInformation where UserName like @userName+'%'", con);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_GetEmployeeData", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USERID", userName);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        // Create an instance of DataSet.
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        con.Close();

        // Return the DataSet as an XmlElement.
        XmlDataDocument xmldata = new XmlDataDocument(ds);
        XmlElement xmlElement = xmldata.DocumentElement;
        return xmlElement;

    }

}
```

Output is mentioned below.

```
<NewDataSet>

    <Table>
        <TimeStamp>2015-10-12T14:53:02.15+05:30</TimeStamp>
        <Name>Albert</Name>
        <Value>1</Value>
    </Table>

    <Table>
        <TimeStamp>2015-10-12T15:17:15.143+05:30</TimeStamp>
        <Name>Albert</Name>
        <Value>12</Value>
    </Table>

</NewDataSet>
```

**Root Tag and Child Tage is NewDataSet and Table. Is it possible to change this tag names ?**

I need to change it as following.

**NewDataSet = Employees**

**Table      = Employee**

Answer (score 0):

Get a string from your xml and do a text-replace:

```
xmlElement.OuterXml.Replace("NewDataSet ", "Employees")
```